# Why does this assembly code segfaults upon printf

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm trying to call a function from a .s file in a .c file, compiled with gcc, in the following way:

print.s

```
.section .data
  str1: .string "Print anything\n"
.section .text
.globl print
print:
  movq $0, %rax
  movq $str1, %rdi
  call printf
```

main.c

```
int main(void){
  print();
  
  return 0;
}
```

and compilling/ running like this:

run.sh

```
as print.s -o print.o
gcc -g -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -static main.o print.o -o print
./print
```

For some reason, the program prints the string "Print anything\n", then quickly segfaults. Why is this happening?

Comment: You forgot the `ret`? Also you misalign the stack but since you zeroed `rax` and the crash is after the print that is not the current problem.

Comment: Use `jmp printf` instead if you want to tail-call and have printf return to your caller.